# Почему телеграмм бот отключается

Tags: telegram-bot

Написал небольшое приложение на java с телеграмм ботом. Загрузил его на хироку. Подключил его в чат. Один день работает, а на второй перестает отвечать в чате. А в самом боте появляется сообщение:

```
Before We can continue We need to verify That you are a real user.
```

Нажимаю подтвердить и бот снова работает. А на следующий день все по новой.
Как это победить?

Comment: используй другой токен

Comment: что значит другой, а у бота он разве не один?

Comment: есть предположение, что этот токен уже кто-то экспроприировал

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591666/telegram-bot-sometimes-requires-user-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы работаете через Telegram API, а для ваших задач необходимо использовать Telegram Bot API. Как говорит документация:

> Этот API позволяет подключать ботов к нашей системе. Боты Telegram - это специальные учетные записи, для которых не требуется дополнительный номер телефона. Эти учетные записи служат интерфейсом для кода, выполняющегося где-то на вашем сервере.

Comment: Я наследую класс от TelegramWebhookBot